# WPF DataTemplate - Access Property of Parent object

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I am customizing the presentation using the HeaderTemplate of a UI item. I would like to access a property of the parent item in the DataTemplate:

```
    <dxa:AccordionItem Header="{Binding SelectedComponents.Count}" Tag="Test" HighlightOnHover="False" HighlightOnPress="False" Margin="0,0,13,0">
                <dxa:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource=Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="DimGray" Height="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxa:AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate>
</dxa:AccordionItem>
```

Basically, I would like to display the Tag property in the DataTemplate.

I have tried:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource=Tag}"
Text="{Binding Path=Tag}"
Text="{Binding ElementName=Tag}"
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to obtain the neccessary binding using the following method:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxa:AccordionItem}}, Path=Tag}"
```